# State not changing - onClick react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling to make my state change...

Basically I have 3 importants functions:

The `run()` function that is triggered `onClick`:

```
  const run = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await setLoadingTrue();
    await translateToEnglish();
    await aiEngine();
  };
```

The `translateToEnglish()` that translate inputs in a form :

```
  const translateToEnglish = async () => {
    try {
      const token = "***********";
      const parameters = {
        mode: "no-cors",
        method: "post",
        auth_key: token,
        text: [description ,  audience],
        target_lang: "EN",
        source_lang: "FR",
      };
      const result = await axios.post(
        "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate",
        querystring.stringify(parameters)
      );
      return setAudienceEN(result.data.translations[1].text)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("there is an error:", err);
    }
   };
```

And `aiEngine()` that works using translated data with the state `audienceEN` previously set in the `translatetoEnglish()` function.

```
  const aiEngine = async () => {
    try {
        const parameters = {
          prompt: `Write an ad for :\n""""""\n${descriptionEN}\n""""""\nThis is the ad aimed at ${audienceEN}:\n""""""`,
        };
        const result = await axios.post(
          "https://api.aiengine.com/",
          parameters,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization:
                "Bearer " + "********",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );
        const sortedResults = result.data.choices.map((val) => val.text);
        setCompletionsEN(sortedResults);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Il y a une erreur : ", err);
    }
  };
```

The problem is that `return setAudienceEN(result.data.translations[1].text)` does not work because when I `console.log(audienceEN)` in `aiEngine()`, its empty and I have unfortunately not idea why...

Any ideas why guys ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post the code where you are doing onClick operation.

Comment: Here it is my friend : `<input className="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Générer" onClick={run} />`

Comment: Please add console.log(result.data.translations[1].text) before setAudienceEN and check what you are getting in it

Comment: please show aiEngine

Comment: @SulemanAhmad `console.log(result.data.translations[1].text)` works well and shows my result. This is why I don't get it :/

Comment: @Viet Done, I added it to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since updating state is asynchronous operation, that may be the reason `aiEngine()` is not getting updated value of `audienceEN` . To handle this you can call `aiEngine()` after the update of `audienceEN` using `useEffect` like:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
     const callAiEngine = async ()=>{
      await aiEngine();
     }
     if(audienceEN){
       callAiEngine();
    }

},[audienceEN])
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I just needed to create a custom hook to not trigger `useEffect()` on first render!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `async operation` and while your response came from `axios post call`, it runs the next line and update the state with empty value. You can try binding `.then` and `.catch` for possible errors. Here it is you can try:

```
   const result = await axios.post(
        "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate",
        querystring.stringify(parameters)
      )
       .then(result=>{
         console.log(result); //console to check your value structure
         return setAudienceEN(result?.data?.translations[1]?.text) //Add it here after checking structure from console
       })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

By doing this hopefully it will work.